# PHP EXCEL multiple files and sheets

Tags: php, excel, phpexcelreader

Before you answer. Please remember its xls and not csv. Plus data is multiple sheets and multiple columns.

I have 50 Excel files in one folder. Data is in different columns.

- Info1 - Label a1 data b1 sheet1
- Info2 - Label a2 data b2 sheet1
- Info3 - label a1 data b1 sheet2
- Info4 - Label a2 data b2 sheet 2

I need to import from all the files into one spreadsheet putting data underneath each other in rows for import.csv into MySQL.

So it must be all record form each file in a new row with the label as header.

500 excel files in one folder. Each having 2 sheets with data not in rows as normal csv but colums where a is the label and b the data. So phpmyadmin wont work as it first needs to change the data from column to row. Making colum a data to cros to row 1 as header and volum b as data in row 2. Then the second excel spreadsheet to row 2 etc etc. Plus the two sheets need to be combined.

Comment: This is a re-ask of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876621/how-to-import-data-from-excel-files-into-mysql). It is better to edit a question into shape than to ask a new one.

Comment: Previous question was marked as closed as they did not understand the question!

Comment: So, edit it so it can be re-opened. It's best not to call people unhelpful either - that really won't help!

Comment: I know , but the answer was shot down first time due to people not reading correctly - all commented as if it was straight forward csv import - and then closed,

Comment: All i need is a point int the right direction on how to accomplish this as all the examples i find in google is for simple rows, not complicated 2 worksheets per file with data being top down and not in row?

Comment: (I've moved a comment I made here to your original question. This is still not clear - please respond there. If you edit that question to make it clear, **and it is about programming**, then it will be reopened).